# Cannot upload new variable to database; improper use of Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell

I don't get any errors when I execute this script, however it does not add the account to my database. I'm lost - any suggestions would be helpful.

Currently using PowerShell 5.1

```
$newAccount = @{
        safe = $FullSafe
        platformID = $platformID
        username = $username
        AccountName = $AccountName
        password = "abc"
        secretType = "key"
        secret = ""
        platformAccountProperties = {}
        DisableAutoMgmt = $disableAutoMgmtReason
        DisableAutoMgmtReason = $disableAutoMgmtReason
            }
$addAccount = $newAccount | ConvertTo-Json

try{
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://"$Environment"/PasswordVault/ -Method post -Body $addAccount -ContentType 'application/json'

}
catch [Exception]
{
$script:errorMessage = $Result
"Error uploading your account"
}

if(($addAccount.StatusCode -eq "200") -and ($addAccount.StatusDescription.Contains("Account added successfully")))
{
   $SuccessAuth = 1
}
elseif(!$errorMessage -eq "")
{
    $errorMessage   
    $SuccessAuth = 0
}

if($SuccessAuth -eq 1){
Write-Host $SuccessAuth
}
else
{
Write-Host 'Unable to get PAM authentication token. Please check username and password'
}

if($SuccessAuth -eq 1){
$AddAccountM = "Account " + $FQDN +" has been stored in PAM tool in safe " + $FullSafe + ". Now the script will trigger password change on this account"
Write-Host $AddAccountM
GetAccountID $device $FQDN
}

else
{
$ADE = "Failed in adding account " + $FQDN +" in PAM tool in safe " + $FullSafe
Write-Host $ADE
}
```

I don't receive any error messages, though I've never used the Try, Catch functions before so I'm not entirely sure if I'm using them properly. Also, I have never used Invoke-RestMethod before so I'm unsure if I'm using all the correct parameters. The If statements after are used to authenticate if the account is actually uploaded or not.

Comment: Your Database has REST APIs? I would imagine `Invoke-Sqlcmd` would be more similar to the DB style.

Comment: Yes it does. Are you saying to replace the Invoke-Rest with that command?

Comment: No, if it has REST APIs, using that is always safer. I don't see any authentication strings being supplied. Since this is only available to you, can you try doing POST from Postman app. They are usually more detailed in the data they return.

Comment: Yes, I have authentication strings used earlier in the script. Should I have posted those as well?

Comment: What i meant is that there are no Auth strings passed as parameters along with the `Invoke-RestMethod`. It would be along the lines of `-UseDefaultCredentials` switch or as a payload for `-Headers` or `-Credentials` depending on the type of auth the API supports

Comment: Do you get any output at all when you run this? There must be something, at least the status code.

Comment: I am unsure. When I run $addAccount.StatusCode it does not return anything.

Comment: Tell me what this line returns. `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://"$Environment"/PasswordVault/ -Method post -Body $addAccount -ContentType 'application/json'` Add it to a variable if u want and output the variable.

Comment: when I create the variable $response = for that line, I have 'Write-Host $response' under it and it does not output anything

Comment: That is really odd. something has to be returned. Since we are trying, try adding `-useDefaultCredential` switch to the `invoke-Restmethod`

Comment: That doesn't work either. Do I need a return statement somewhere?

Comment: If the command itself isn't returning anything, there is nothing you can do. Perhaps go over the API documentation.

Comment: Can you try `Invoke-WebRequest` instead and list the output?